# Smart merging in R

Tags: r, merge

I have two datasets:

```
df1=read.csv("C:/Users/synthex/Desktop/111.csv", sep=";",dec=",")
    structure(list(id = 1:10, mark = structure(c(3L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 
    2L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 1L), .Label = c("6,50-16 Я-387-1", "cvb", 
    "ert", "fgdhj", "fgj", "ghm", "jgfh", "ng", "vbn,"), class = "factor"), 
        gost = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 2L
        ), .Label = c("gost1", "gost10", "gost2", "gost3", "gost4", 
        "gost5", "gost6", "gost7", "gost8", "gost9"), class = "factor"), 
        number = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), man = structure(c(1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "voltar", class = "factor"), 
        price = 67:76), .Names = c("id", "mark", "gost", "number", 
    "man", "price"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

The second dataset

```
     df2=read.csv("C:/Users/synthex/Desktop/112.csv", sep=";",dec=",")
   structure(list(id = c(10L, 10L, NA, 18L, 18L, NA, 7L, 7L, NA, 
10L, 4L), id.1 = structure(c(6L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 
1L, 6L, 5L), .Label = c("", "et", "rey", "rty", "ryy1", "The Tire 6,50-16 I-387-1", 
"utreu"), class = "factor"), Weight = structure(c(1L, 5L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("", "0.5339173", 
"0.5349673", "0.5361807", "0.5372405"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", 
"id.1", "Weight"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L
))
```

I must join this dataset by id

```
a1=merge(df1, df2, by = "id")
```

In output i get the wrong format of table, like this

```
id                        ido   Weight            mark      gost    number  man  price
10  The Tire 6,50-16 I-387-1                6,50-16 Я-387-1 gost    4   voltar
10  The Tire 6,50-16 I-387-1    0.3926514   6,50-16 Я-387-1 gost    4   voltar
10  The Tire 6,50-16 I-387-1    0.3803419   6,50-16 Я-387-1 gost    4   voltar
10  The Tire 6,50-16 I-387-1    0.3841079   6,50-16 Я-387-1 gost    4   voltar
10  The Tire 6,50-16 I-387-1    0.4272772   6,50-16 Я-387-1 gost    4   voltar
10  The Tire 6,50-16 I-387-1    0.4442845   6,50-16 Я-387-1 gost    4   voltar
10  The Tire 6,50-16 I-387-1                6,50-16 Я-387-1 gost    4   voltar
10  The Tire 6,50-16 I-387-1                6,50-16 Я-387-1 gost    4   voltar
10  The Tire 6,50-16 I-387-1                6,50-16 Я-387-1 gost    4   voltar
10  The Tire 6,50-16 I-387-1                6,50-16 Я-387-1 gost    4   voltar
```

but i need this format.See the screen.
I.E. The corresponding id is assigned opposite, in this case, here three times the  id №10 is duplicated

[image: needed format]

How to merge tables to get the desired format?
ordering must be

```
10
1
10
2
10
3
11
1
11
2
...
```

Comment: Can you clarify a little bit what you are saying in the end about the desired format, about the id being assigned opposite or something? I really struggle to understand what you mean...

Comment: @ArthurSpoon, yes, you are right, namely the id being assigned opposite like in screen.

Comment: My question was actually: what do you mean by "assigned opposite"?

Comment: When you give the ordering at the end of your question, is is unclear what it is all about. Can you try to make it clear by saying, for example, "I want to order my rows depending on the columns X and Y". Without understanding what result you want in terms of included rows and ordering, it is impossible to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's make `id` as a factor because it makes sense:

```
df1$id <- as.factor(df1$id)
df2$id <- as.factor(df2$id)
```

Then we can merge the dataset and specify if we want to keep all rows from one dataset even if they don't have any match in the other with `all.x` (keep rows from `df1`) and `all.y` (keep rows from `df2`). I also clean up a bit by drop lines with a `NA` `id`:

```
library(tidyr) # For the drop_na()

(df <- merge(df1, df2, by = "id", all.y = T) %>% drop_na(id))
  id            mark   gost number    man price                     id.1    Weight
1  4             ghm  gost4      4 voltar    70                     ryy1 0.5339173
2  7            jgfh  gost7      4 voltar    73                      rty 0.5349673
3  7            jgfh  gost7      4 voltar    73                    utreu          
4 10 6,50-16 Я-387-1 gost10      4 voltar    76                       et 0.5372405
5 10 6,50-16 Я-387-1 gost10      4 voltar    76 The Tire 6,50-16 I-387-1          
6 10 6,50-16 Я-387-1 gost10      4 voltar    76 The Tire 6,50-16 I-387-1          
7 18            <NA>   <NA>     NA   <NA>    NA                      rey 0.5361807
8 18            <NA>   <NA>     NA   <NA>    NA                       et
```

Comment: @D.Joe I think I know what you want: having all the values from `df2` even if they don't have a matching row in `df1`?

Comment: Yes,but there must be a correspondence in  id:
10
4
they can not be divided.
The fact is that we are dealing with weights.
Initially, I compared mydat1 and mydat2  and received weights of correspondence .
for example, when comparing row 10(mydat1) and row  4(mydat2), the weight was 0.53
and 10 (mydat1) and 10 (mydata2) the correspondence 0.537. Do you understand what i mean? Like in screen 10 and 4 together near with it weight

Comment: What do you mean "there must be a correspondence `id` 10:4"? Are those two IDs supposed to represent the same thing? If so, why are they not the same ID?

Comment: they do not mean the same thing.
OK. there is a line4 in the Mydat1 and line 10 in the Mydat2,
calculate the weight

rpairs_jar <- compare.linkage(mydat1, mydat2,
                              strcmp = c("id"),
                              strcmpfun = jarowinkler)

rpairs_epiwt <- epiWeights(rpairs_jar)

getPairs(rpairs_epiwt, max.weight = Inf, min.weight = -Inf)


did you understand how get weights?
We can get weight between 10 line and 9 line 
after it is done, we got df2 and must join it to df1

Comment: I have no idea what you're saying, but please update your question rather than adding comments. Otherwise, I feel like I have the exact same data frame as the one you give as your desired output, apart from the ordering, so I don't understand your question. If your issue is about ordering, then this should be made clear in the question. And without any sort of context and knowledge of the data you're talking about, what you're saying about Mydat1 and its lines and weight values and whatnot, it is just impossible for me to understand what you are talking about.

Comment: If your issue is about ordering, then this should be made clear in the question. Exactly in  ordering, i edited my post, please look at the end))